# windows can't open the file, v.in.ascii

Tags: grass-gis, windows

I am using GRASS 7 for windows, and I'm having trouble running `v.in.ascii`, although I'm fairly sure I've run it successfully before. When I run `v.in.ascii`, I get an error: Windows can't open this file. 
[image]

This happens through the command line and the gui. Other `v.*.exe` commands seem to run properly.

I thought maybe there was a path clash somewhere, so I generally cleaned up my path variable (e.g., removing OSGeo4W/bin). I also reinstalled GRASS 7. I searched GRASS bugs, but didn't find something similar. Other than that, I haven't been able to find anything on google to help explain this, and I've run out of ideas.

Recently, IT installed hard drive encryption software. This and a couple problems popped up about the same time, so I have a sneaking suspicion that it's related.

Edit: some additional information that @GeoStoneMarten helped me tease out:

- From the GRASS shell, if I cd to C:\grass70\bin, then `v.in.ascii` works
- `v.in.ascii` is the *only* `v.*` command that gives me this error
- C:\grass70\bin is being added to the path variable correctly upon calling grass70.bat

Comment: have you check in install folder if  v.in.ascii.exe exists?

Comment: @GeoStoneMarten Thanks for the help. Yes, C:\grass70\bin\v.in.ascii.exe exists. It's also more than 0KB - I was curious about that too.

Comment: i check it on grass 6 and size = 126 Ko (129 550 octets) i install wingrass 7 and comeback

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time. Just FYI, v.in.ascii.exe is 129 kb on my machine, so I imagine the executable is intact.

Comment: this is equivalent for me (128kb). Are you running from *.bat  because *.bat set PATH at starting application. in addition check if  v.in.ascii.bat exist and it content

Comment: Yes, I start grass by running C:\grass70\grass70.bat and then I run v.in.ascii. 
There is no file called v.in.ascii.bat under C:\grass70 (there is only v.in.ascii.exe). Should there be v.in.ascii.bat?

Comment: can you run in command line `v.in.ascii --help`

Comment: No, I get the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32689/discussion-between-geostonemarten-and-user55937).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why, but there was a 0 kb file called v.in.ascii in C:\Users\username. I deleted that file and everything works again.

Edit: Just a quick update. I usually call GRASS from Windows' absolutely deplorable command prompt (I shouldn't do that). If I mistype a command, I can't hit the up button to recover what I had typed so that I can try again. So instead I copy and paste the command to not start from scratch. In my haste, I copied the directory and tried to execute `C:\Users\username>v.in.ascii ...`, which results in a sensible error but succeeds in redirecting nothing to a file called v.in.ascii, thus blocking me from using that module. Mystery solved. My error, but I blame Windows.